# How to assign an integer to a variable of type char

Tags: c++

I'm not doing something right here.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char a='2Z';
  cout<<a<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But only `Z` is printed and not the `2` proceeding it. How can print the integer too?

Comment: A `char` can only contain a single character. You want a std::string.

Comment: A `char` can only hold 1 character. If you want more then one character use `std::string`. Also note that `'x'` is used for a literal character and `"xx"` is used for a literal string,.

Comment: This question is probably relevant, and definitely informative here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to store a string of multiple characters?  Are you trying to store a single multibyte character?  Are you trying to store an actual `int` value into a single-byte `char` type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* wanted `std::string a = "2Z";` instead. Note the double quotation characters, and the change of type.

`'2Z'` is a *multicharacter constant* with an implementation-defined value, but a type `int`.

Most likely it's `256 * '2' + 'Z'`. That's likely to be too big to fit into a `char`, and if `char` is `signed` on your platform, then that narrowing conversion again will be implementation defined. You get only the `Z` as your implementation seems to be computing `(256 * '2' + 'Z') % 256` which is `'Z'`.

In other words, multicharacter constants are best avoided, as are narrowing conversions to `char` types.

Comment: I've seen (clear|evil) use of multicharacter constants, when every constant would be 4 characters and their values would have semantic meaning, reading as 4-characters (abbreviated) English words. Poor man's self-reflective enums.

Comment: @SergeyA: So have I. In some kernel code too. And my favourite answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550674/this-source-code-is-switching-on-a-string-in-c-how-does-it-do-that/45550696#45550696

Comment: Your favorite answer is the one wrote by yourself? And I thought of myself as a narcissist! :)))

Comment: @SergeyA: Ha. In all fairness I meant the favourite answer I've given. But let's leave my other comment in; there's nothing wrong with a bit of hubris from time to time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems there, first you have single quotes, second you want to keep in one char a string, solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 const char *a="2Z";
 char str[] = "234";
 std::string aString = "4444ZZZZZ"; // Using STD namespace

 cout<<a<<endl;
 cout<<str<<endl;
 cout<<aString<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who is downvoting, please be so kind and explain what is the reason.

Comment: @Simon NMDV, but isn't `std::string` to be preferred?

Comment: It depends on the situation, but in the question is not mentioned this.