# Weird output when using merge() function in Standard template library in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge, stl

```
// merge.cpp
// merges two containers into a third
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> //for merge()
using namespace std;
int src1[] = { 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 };
int src2[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
int dest[8];
int main()
{ //merge src1 and src2 into dest
    merge(src1, src1+5, src2, src2+3, dest);
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++) //display dest
    cout << dest[j] << '  ';
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code that I typed and what I expected was a sorted merged array, but the output came out to be :

```
1210537622105376321053763210537642105376521053766210537682105376
```

I varied the data, rechecked the syntax but every thing is fine , I think

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mistake in this code is very obvious. But yet if someone needs it in future, I can tell you what mistake I had done in this code.

### Location of mistake

```
cout << dest[j] << '  '; //<----------the mistake is here,
```

### Theory

Single quotes are in c/c++ used to enclose single characters.
Like `'c'`, `'+'` similarly `' '`.

Blank space in c/c++ is considered a single character.
Double quotes are used to enclose multi-character strings.

### Solution

So either replace `''` by `" "`, or replace `'  '`(two blank spaces) by `' '`(single blank space).

Answer (score 7):

In c++ this is a character `' '` (single quotation marks) and this is a string `" "` (double quotation marks). Avoid to use single quotation marks for more than one character as it is implementation defined.

Fix

```
cout << dest[j] << '  ';
```

to

```
cout << dest[j] << ' '; // remove one whitespace
```

or

```
cout << dest[j] << "  "; // change to string
```

A multi-character character constant is interpreted as integer. In your case `'  '` is `2105376`. With g++ and clang++ `'  '` is translated to `8224 = 256 * ' ' + ' '`. In your example either you forgot one whitespace or your compiler translates with a different method: `2105376 = 256 * 256 * ' ' + 256 * ' '+ ' '`

Enable and read compiler warnings. This was the first thing the compiler told me.

```
:13:24: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

Comment: @rishabh Note: your compiler seems to be interpreting `'  '` as `2105376` which explains your output

Comment: they are allowed but their interpretation is implementation defined

Comment: It **is** allow d to have more than one character between single quotes, but it’s not generally useful. It’s a [multi character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) (see item 6); it’s type is `int` and its value is implementation-defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Although this is one use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550674/this-source-code-is-switching-on-a-string-in-c-how-does-it-do-that/45550696#45550696

Comment: @Bathsheba — that’s clever, but I’d be more inclined to use named constants. They’re less prone to compiling when there’s a typo.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Absolutely!

Answer (score 6):

`'  '` is a *multicharacter literal*, as it encloses more than one character. It's an `int` type and has an implementation defined value, although `256 * ' ' + ' '` is common. Because it's an `int`, a different `ostream` overload to the `char` one is used, which accounts for your output.

Use `"  "` instead.