# reading strings with switch case C language

Tags: c

i have a problem making a switch case read a string instead of just a number, if it's possible, I want it to read both. any advice on how to do that ? thanks

Comment: Do you want to compare a string with some possibilities using switch/case (and there is already an answer for that) ? Else please clarify because I do not understand what you say about 'read'

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible: the case labels must be compile time evaluable integral types in C.

If you need anything else, then use an `if` block, using `strcmp` &c.

(Although some folk when writing non-portable code might use multicharacter constants as case labels: see [This source code is switching on a string in C. How does it do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550674/this-source-code-is-switching-on-a-string-in-c-how-does-it-do-that))

Comment: Write a complete c program that implements Queues with three functions
a. Enqueue()
b. Dequeue()
c. Display()
The program should take “strings” as user input.

Comment: that was what i was asked to do

Comment: is there a way that i can show my code here? sorry first time posting here

Comment: @NicolasPorras: I don't see any need for that. Why can't you use an `if` block as I suggested/